# Need to create a new dictionary from an existing dictionary in a different format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My original dictionary is dict1.

```
dict1={'Input.txt':'Randy','Code.py':'Stan','Output.txt':'Randy'}
```

I need the output as below

```
{'Randy':['Input.txt','Output.txt'],'Stan':['Code.py']}
```

Comment: When tackling a problem like this, I usually step away from my computer and write **in words** the steps I need to take to solve the problem. Sometimes it helps to imagine doing the task by hand. Once I have a clear description, then I attempt to translate my description into code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't write my thought process, but I do exactly think how I would do it if I were a robot :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neat Python skills:

```
dict1 = {'Input.txt':'Randy','Code.py':'Stan','Output.txt':'Randy'}
out = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    out.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

giving the expected:

```
{'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```

---

So we iterate over the key, value pairs in sync by unpacking the tuples returned from the dictionaries `.items()` method. For each pair, we set the value (i.e. `'Randy'`, `'Stan'`, `'Randy'`) as a key to a new list in the output dictionary if there is not already a list there - this is done neatly with the `setdefault` method.

Because the return value from `setdefault` will either be the new list we just created or the already populated list (in the case of the `'Output.txt'` pair) and the fact that lists are mutable (changes to them affect all references to them), we can just append our key (`'Input.txt'`, `'Code.py'`, `'Output.txt'`) straight to *whatever* is returned, new or old.